# SimplePanorama library from github for displaying 360 degree photos

Tags: android, github, move, photo, panning

I am using android SimplePanorama library from github for displaying 360 degree photos.

I need to move 360 degree photo to any camera angle slowly using code without acceleration enable.

```
sphericalView = (SphericalView) findViewById(R.id.spherical_view);
sphericalView.getCamera().setRotation(10,800,10000);
sphericalView.setPanorama(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.drawable.three), true);
```

please help